# html table sorting doesn't work with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, sorting, html-table

I am trying to sort my table with angularJS in function of the column name, but my table is not reacting.
Here is my html table:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr > 
        <th ng-repeat="(i,facet) in voies.parameters.facet"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleSort(i)">{{voies.parameters.facet[i]}}</button></th>
    </tr> 
<tr  ng-repeat="(i,fields) in voies.records" | orderBy:sortColumn:reverse>
  <td>{{voies.records[i].fields.joueur}}</td>
  <td>{{voies.records[i].fields.name}}</td>
  <td>{{voies.records[i].fields.point}}</td>
  <td>{{voies.records[i].fields.club}}</td>
  <td>{{voies.records[i].fields.country}}</td>
  <td>{{voies.records[i].fields.vote}}</td>
  <td>{{voies.records[i].fields.poste}}</td>
  <td>{{voies.records[i].fields.continent}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$scope.toggleSort = function(index) {
    console.info(index);
if($scope.sortColumn === $scope.voies.parameters.facet[index]){
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
}                    
    $scope.sortColumn = $scope.voies.parameters.facet[index];
};
```

My data is loaded from this link: [dataBase](http://public.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search?dataset=resultat_ballon_d_or_2014&rows=30&facet=vote&facet=country&facet=joueur&facet=point&facet=continent&facet=poste&facet=club)

Any help would be more than welcome!

Comment: Maybe toss this in a JsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/), edit post, and add link to it?

Comment: Looks ok to me, except for the typo in the second ng-repeat: http://jsfiddle.net/n36b9/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code [works perfectly well](http://jsfiddle.net/n36b9/8/) when I fix this typo:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(i,fields) in voies.records" | orderBy:sortColumn:reverse>
```

Should be

```
<tr ng-repeat="(i,fields) in voies.records | orderBy:sortColumn:reverse">
```

Also, note that the `ng-repeat` iterator gives you the actual object ("facet", "fields"), so you don't need to use the indexer.  Instead of this:

```
<td>{{voies.records[i].fields.joueur}}</td>
```

You should use simply:

```
<td>{{fields.joueur}}</td>
```